# How to create a regular expression that would find all pieces of text BETWEEN certain sets of characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string that looks like 'E10 1/05/03 2/3211 3/AO Yuzhmor'.
The pieces that i need to extract are the ones following `' \d\/'`:

```
1) 05/03
2) 3211
3) AO Yuzhmor
```

My last idea was `' \d\/(.*?)(?=(( \d\/)|\Z))'`

but it still wouldn't work properly on the last piece (the |\Z instruction doesn't seem to do anything).

Comment: Are the delimiters always numbered 1, 2 and 3, and are there just 3 of them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. This works for your example:

```
>>> s = 'E10 1/05/03 2/3211 3/AO Yuzhmor'
>>> re.findall('\s\d\/(.*?)(?=\s\d\/|$)', s)
['05/03', '3211', 'AO Yuzhmor']
```

Explanation:
Match on `[space][digit]/`, capturing everything that follows using a non-greedy quantifier, until the current position is immediately before either another `[space][digit]/` (detected using a lookahead, matched but not consumed) or the end of the input. Use `findall` to return all matching instances in the input.

Comment: Thank You very much, your re really does work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky because we don't know all of the rules of how these strings are built. One option is to use your regex to split the string

```
>>> re.split(r" \d/", 'E10 1/05/03 2/3211 3/AO Yuzhmor')[1:]
['05/03', '3211', 'AO Yuzhmor']
```

Another is to be more specific about the fields, assuming that they are always " 1/", " 2/" and " 3/"

```
>>> re.match(r".*?1/(.*?) 2/(.*?) 3/(.*)", 'E10 1/05/03 2/3211 3/AO Yuzhmor').groups()
('05/03', '3211', 'AO Yuzhmor')
```

Comment: Thank a lot for a great idea with 're.split'!

Comment: *"we don't know all of the rules of how these strings are built"* the #1 cause of bickering about regex (whether on SO or not).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
re.findall('\d/(\S+)', s)
```

:)